# Twitter Search API: Change result_type to random

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, api, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I'm attempting to create a web page which displays a single random tweet containing a certain keyword. Right now, I can get a single tweet containing the keyword, but it has to be either popular or recent or mixed based on the result_type parameter.

Is it possible to do this using the Twitter Search API, or is there a way to complete this using the Twitter Stream API?

Comment: Sure, use the [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) lib with `search/tweets` endpoint with a param of `'count'  => 100, 'result_type' => 'recent'` then [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the response and pick one or use [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

Comment: There is no random `result_type` so you need to implement it yourself. Options are (mixed, recent and popular) - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html